# How to update clashing values in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Say I have a  I have the following table:

```
Numbers
=======
   1
   2
   2
   1
```

Using MySql (MyISAM), how do I convert the 1's to 2's and the 2's to 1's?

For example, this won't work:

```
UPDATE `MyTable` SET `Numbers` = 1 WHERE `Numbers` = 2;
UPDATE `MyTable` SET `Numbers` = 2 WHERE `Numbers` = 1;
```

The first statement will convert all of the 2's to 1's before the second statement executes.  The result will be:

```
Numbers
=======
   2
   2
   2
   2
```

What I need is this:

```
Numbers
=======
   2
   1
   1
   2
```

Is it possible using only MySQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Numbers = CASE Numbers
                WHEN 1 THEN 2
                WHEN 2 then 1
              END
WHERE Numbers IN (1, 2)
```

or

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Numbers = IF(Numbers = 1, 2, 1)
WHERE Numbers iN (1, 2)
```

or

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Numbers = 3 - Numbers
WHERE Numbers iN (1, 2)
```

The first version generalizes to multiple cases more easily.

Comment: Thanks Barmar.  Is it necessary to include "WHERE Numbers IN (1,2)" in the first version?  Did you include it just to improve performance by narrowing the record set?

Comment: If you don't do that, I think it will set all other numbers to `NULL`, unless you add `ELSE Numbers` to the `CASE` expression. It should also improve performance, since it doesn't have to perform the `CASE` tests for all the irrelevant rows.

Comment: @Steven George: Since that CASE expression will return NULL for rows that don't have a match in WHEN, it will update ALL rows in the table, and replace values other than 1 or 2 with a NULL. (I'm sometimes chastised for including the `ELSE NULL` in my CASE expression, but it's there, even when it's not specified.) To remove the WHERE clause, we'd want an `ELSE Numbers` in the CASE expression. Not inadvertently changing other rows is of first importance. Using the WHERE clause may also improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm good at calling sql not changing it but this might work... the problem is that you are executing two different statements, you need to combine them some how..

```
 UPDATE `MyTable` SET `Numbers` = 1 WHERE `Numbers` = 2 
 and if `Numbers` = 2 WHERE `Numbers` = 1;
```